# initializing value of a map which is a field inside a structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, initialization, structure

When I am trying to insert a value to my map (named child) it gives segmentation fault. I am unable to understand what exactly is the problem my method(both commented and non-commented one).

```
struct trienode{
    map < char , struct trienode* > child;
    bool eow;
}; typedef struct trienode trienode;

void insert_trie(trienode* root,string mystr){

    int len = mystr.length();
    int p=0;
    char ch=mystr.at(p);
    trienode* temp=root;
    while(p<len){
        map<char, trienode* >::iterator itr=(temp->child).find(ch);

        if( itr!=(temp->child).end()){
            temp=itr->second;
            p++;
            ch=mystr.at(p);
        }
        else{
            trienode* temp2;
            temp2=(trienode*)malloc(sizeof(trienode));
            temp->child.insert(make_pair(ch,temp2));//segmentation fault occure on this line or line below it.
            //(temp->child)[ch]=temp2;
            if(p==len-1){
                temp2->eow=true;
            }
            else{
                temp2->eow= false;
                temp=temp2;
            }
            p++;
            ch=mystr.at(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?  See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/
) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: you need to use `new`, not `malloc`. otherwise `std::map` would not be initialized.

Comment: Comments:  You don't need the typedef - C++ does that anyway.  I would do the `p++;ch=mystr.at(p)` outside the if/else.  In fact, I would make the while loop a for-loop `for (size_t p = 0; p<len; p++)`, and then make the first statement in the loop be: `const char ch=mystr.at(p);` (Your current code will fail if `mystr` is empty.)

Comment: @appleapple: Make that an answer.

Comment: @MartinBonner I didn't make a answer because I did not fully read the question, and not sure it's the core problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `new`, not `malloc`. otherwise the `std::map` would not be initialized. and the segment fault probably happens inside `std::map`'s copy constructor.

---

- You can use `std::map<char,trienode>` for `child` and avoid all these bugs.
- `std::map::operator[]` insert item for you, if you make sure `trienode::eow` initialize to false, you can rely on it.